# Is there a way to revert eclipse android ADT from r17 to r16 since javadoc and source attachment is broken?

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc, libraries, adt

In ADT r17 there have been changes to the ADT where libraries should be placed in "libs" and somehow autodetected for use in the project. Unfortunately I have found no way to set javadoc and source attachment on the auto-imported jars. [Some suggest moving jars back to lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-add-javadoc-to-libraries-with-adt-r17) and exporting them, but this creates local folder references in my .classpath and we like to have this file checked in.

I haven't found a way to revert to an earlier ADT. I am happy to use r16. Is there a way to revert to this earlier version?

EDIT:
As suggested in the answers, I tried to revert through the eclipse installation history. I got this:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
```

Comment: which IDE you are using? eclipse?

Comment: Yes, eclipse. It's in the title, but I have added the tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the ADT on its own (as opposed to a matching pair of ADT and SDK Tools as recommended) then I believe that this link will get you a zip with it in:

[ADT-16.0.0.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.0.zip)

So if you uninstall the ADT r17 (or 18) items and then install from archive you will have reverted. As it's recommended to use matching Tools and ADT, I've not tried it myself,so it's at your own risk!

Comment: I'm glad it works. I'm just using the export trick and jars in lib myself as I don't care about the .classpath. I hope they fix it properly soon.

Comment: Agree. I can add that I also had to download sdk r16 and avoid upgrading it to a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure because I haven't tried, Goto

`Help->About Eclipse SDK->Insallation Details->Installation History tab`.

From there you can get the history of your installations, try to select previous installation and revert.

Comment: If this works then good, rest u can do.

Help -> Install new Softwares -> already installed -> Installation History.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately it didn't work: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,16.0.1.v201112150204-238534