# Offline JavaDocs for JARs in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, offline

Would you know whether it's possible to store javadocs linked to jars so that they are available when not connected to the internet?

It seems that sometimes I can download javadocs for offline access, but not always.

For example, I would like to have [this](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html) for offline access. How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try attaching the src jar to the library.

Take a look at this :

[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)

In your case you would download and use the following jar.
http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/downloads/robolectric-0.9.4-src.jar

Once you have attached the src jar you also have access to the Javadoc in the javadocs view.

### Is there a Javadoc repository ?

To answer another part of your question, I do not know of an offline repository, but there is an online one worth exploring : http://www.docjar.org/

There is also an Eclipse plugin for docjar which can be installed using from **[here](http://www.docjar.com/plugin1.html)**.

Having said that, I don't think they would go to the trouble of generating javadoc for third part libraries like `roboelectric` which provide one themselves. In that case, you are stuck generating the Javadocs manually using the steps in the following section.

### Generating Javadoc from src.jar

**tl;dr** : Using the steps below, I generated the Javadoc from the `robolectric-0.9.4-src.jar` source jar. The javadoc thus generated can be downloaded from **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn9dzrey15x2m1e/robolectric-0.9.4-javadoc.7z)**.

**Step 1**: 
Extract the `robolectric-0.9.4-src.jar` (using 7-zip or another archive utility). Move the `android` , `com` and `META-INF` folder inside a folder called `src` (This is useful in the next step). Let's say you extracted the `robolectric-0.9.4-src.jar` inside  `c:\robo`. It would now have the following folders :
`c:\robo\src\android`
`c:\robo\src\com`
`c:\robo\src\META-INF`

**Step 2**:
Create an Eclipse project using the extracted source. This can be done by creating a new Java project inside Eclipse and instead of using the default workspace location, point to the location of the directory above (`c:\robo`).

[image]

**Step 3**:
Now run the javadoc wizard by going to `File -> Export -> Javadoc` like so :

[image]

**Step 4**:
Select 'Private' package to get Javadoc for all classes.
[image]

**Step 5**:
Next, select all jars except `tools.jar` in referenced jars :
[image]

**Step 6**:
Then, choose the path of the `overview` html and Check `Open Generated File in browser`:
[image]

**Step 7**:
Click on Finish. On doing so, you'll see the Javadoc task running in the Debug view :

[image]

And when it finishes a browser view should open with your Javadoc ! 
[image]

**Step 8**:
Profit ! Your Javadoc should now be generated and accessible.

Comment: Great, thanks, but this is for the source to give me context sensitive help in eclipse correct?  This is something that will be very helpful too but is it not possible to view it using HTML like on the link I showed ?   The eclipse "javadocs view" only show context sensitive help, right?  You cant search for a class etc?

Comment: @Martin, though I have not tried it you should be able to generate the 'html' javadoc from the source jar. Let me update my answer with how to do that.

Comment: @Martin, I have updated my answer with the generic steps to generate the Javadoc given a source jar. I have also generated the javadocs for `roboelectric-0.9.4` (The link to the archived javadoc is in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to see the source code and Javadocs for the third-party libraries your project depends on during debugging, for instance.

You can do this: open a class that is in such a library in an editor. You will see an "Attach Source..." button. Click on it and navigate to the source archive for the project. Once located and attached, you will be able to see the entire source code and also Javadocs when needed.