# Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android programming and I was creating a simple app from a tutorial when I got an error on debug.
In the tutorial the app contains a button that counts how many times it's pressed, and that project works, but I edited the project to create an app with two buttons, one button counts how many times it's pressed (with a simple if-else) and other reset the counting.
This modified app doesn't work.

These are code errors and code files:

Errors:

```
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flavio.tictactoe/com.flavio.tictactoe.TicTacToe}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at com.flavio.tictactoe.TicTacToe.onCreate(TicTacToe.java:24)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
11-25 21:47:32.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6865):     ... 11 more
```

TicTacToe.java(yes, I know it isn't a tic tac toe app :) ):

```
package com.flavio.tictactoe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

public class TicTacToe extends Activity 
implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button;
int touchCount;
String number;
Button ResetButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
button = new Button(this);
button=((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_count));
button.setText( "Touch me!" );
button.setOnClickListener(this);
ResetButton=new Button(this);
ResetButton=((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_reset));
ResetButton.setText("Reset");
ResetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
setContentView(R.id.button_count);
setContentView(R.id.button_reset);

}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button_count:
        touchCount++;
        if(touchCount>1){
            number=" times";
            }else{
                number=" time";
                }

        button.setText("Touched me " + touchCount + number);
    case R.id.button_reset:
        touchCount=0;
        if(touchCount>1){
            number=" times";
            }else{
                number=" time";
                }

    }
    }
}
```

activity_tic_tac_toe.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TicTacToe" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_count"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S. I have got a problem with android.jar file: every time I want to see a .class file, eclipse tells me 'Source not found'

Comment: Please don't apologise for your English.  It's better than a lot of native English speakers.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it (but I admit to checked my text with google translate :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setContentView()` to display your `activity_tic_tac_toe` layout first. Then you can use `findViewById()` to fetch the Buttons, or any other View, within this layout:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe); // The layout that holds your Buttons

button=((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_count));
button.setText( "Touch me!" );
button.setOnClickListener(this);

ResetButton=((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_reset));
ResetButton.setText("Reset");
ResetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

(Notice that I removed some unnecessary lines.)

---

> P.S. I have got a problem with android.jar file: every time I want to see a .class file, eclipse tells me 'Source not found'

Are you trying to look through the source code? Click <kbd>Attach Source Code</kbd> and point it towards your copy of the Android SDK.

If you don't have that option, read this question: [How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9873152/1267661)

Comment: I'll accept that as a "Thank you!", and reply: "You're welcome!" :)