# How do I set the Java Doc for google drive api for android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api, javadoc

I am using the google drive api for android in eclipse, how do I link the documentation so that when I hover over something, I can view the java doc for it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I can't really figure out how to do it, and some of the documentation online is confusing.

Comment: Have you tried using sources.jar in the libs

Comment: to pop up when i hover over something? or to go into the the jar and fins it that way.. I'm looking for a on the fly kinda thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Android Development Tools (ADT), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579339/1369991 on how to do it.

Note that the contents of the libs folder will be bundled with your application. So you really should put the source and Javadoc JARs in another folder or even keep them outside of your workspace. Everything described in that answer also works with external JARs -- on Windows you just have to use `\\` or `/` instead of the usual `\` as path separator.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have sources OR the java doc for any of the jars for this..

Comment: The [API download](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) contains JARs for the sources and the Javadocs.

Comment: So how do I add those, by making the .properties file for each jar? Where is the location of the jars

Comment: Did you look into the downloaded file? Did you read the answer I've linked to. What else do you need? Reading your initial question, I really thought, you already had the Javadocs and just didn't know how to integrate them into the IDE -- that's the only tricky part. Take some initiative, please.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) and the 3rd dot says [Importing the latest Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/googleapis)

Comment: This doesnt give me sources and java doc so when I hover over something  it says what it should.. for when using google api stuff