# Android app storage path returning null only for .jar classes

Tags: android, local-storage, robospice

Here is the issue.  I have two separate classes I include into my app.  One is an advertising SDK the other is RoboSpice.  Both I don't have the source on they are just .jar files I include.  When those applications try to get the path to external storage to write temp files they are getting back null.  I know that because of the logs they dump to the console.  However in my own source code if I use I assume the same routines such as getexternalstorage() it returns the path and lets me save files just fine.  Seeing as I don't have the source code for these classes I can't step through to debug I can only rely on what they write to the console.

Now full story.  This project was one I inherited from another developer.  They used Maven in the project and some of the dependencies relied on non-public Maven sources.  So I went ahead and converted it to a standard eclipse project.  The old compiled source has robospice temp files stored on my testing devices at /data/data//cache so I know the old source was writing to the device just fine in the past.  Any ideas on why compiled sources wouldn't be able to get proper storage locations on the device?

Comment: So.. in your project, you've never got this to work?

Comment: @Math if I write to temp storage using my source code in the non-maven project it works.  If an external class tries to write to temp storage in the non-maven project it does not.  However in the old maven project robospice did successfully create and write cache files.

Comment: For those curious this issue ended up because I was sending the Activity context versus the App Context to one of my classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the sources of the libs you use using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9873152/693752) in eclipse.

RS is open source and it's source code can be located easily on [it's github repo](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice).

RS 1.4.6 supports setting a custom path for cache files, you will have to define your own RS service for that. The starter guide details the way this can be achieved.