# Where to put javadoc, jar and sourcefiles in Eclipse

Tags: java, installation, javadoc

I would like to use an external library for android development and the download for the library came with a jar, javadoc and sourcefiles.(https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/downloads/list)

I understand that the jar goes into the libs in your project, but where exactly do the other two folders go?

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach javadoc and source files to the .jar (from /libs folder). Check this link 
[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)

Answer (score 1):

If I true understanding, you want attach sources and java doc to jar file.
If it right, then

Project Name -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

Expand requared jar file and you see child nodes Source attachment and Javadoc location.
Choose it and press button "Edit", and attach requared file.