# I got a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, dx

even though the class path had the jars I was using, Then I added the jars to dx tool and it gave me java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity xyz java.lang.RuntimeException:

Stub! You are bundling a stubbed jar in the apk! Please move it to the classpath instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-for-code-in-an-java-library-on-android

Comment: look this and conform http://stackoverflow.com/a/11579339

Comment: I am not using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the uses-library entry in the manifest file