# Referenced Javadoc not showing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am developping a library for Android applications in Eclipse and I have added some Javadoc to the classes and methods that are visible to my users. I've generated the javadoc with Project->Generate Javadoc... Then, it created a `doc` folder containing all my Javadoc.

In an Android application using my library, I've referenced the javadoc by right-cliking my library in the `Referenced Libraries` section of my application in the `Package Explorer` and going into `Properties`. Then, in the section `Javadoc Location`, I've linked the created `doc` folder. When I click on `Validate...`, it tells me

> Location is likely valid. Files 'package-list' and 'index.html' have been found.

And if I click `Open in Browser`, I can see all my Javadoc perfectly.

But when I want to see the Javadoc in Eclipse by hovering a class or method of my library that I know has Javadoc, it tells me

> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

I've tried restarting Eclipse, but it didn't help. Why can't I see my Javadoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section `Referencing unpacked javadocs` of the best answer in the following post did the trick!

[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)