# Android Add javadoc to Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, javadoc, libs

**My Goal:** Add javadoc to a 3rd party library in Android Studio. (Specifically Parse)

**My Setup**: I'm using Android Studio 0.5.2 and it's a gradle setup. I stuck the jar library in the /libs folder and updated the gradle file. (Ex - It's a parse library so *compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs/Parse-1.5.0', include: ['*.jar'])* worked.)

**What I tried:**
I was given the documentation as a list of html files. Dropped them in the project in the libs folder and nothing worked. I then used *jar cvf* to create a javadoc in jar format and tried to link to it the *.jar.properties file. Still nothing worked. I know you can get javadocs working because the Android support libraries are pulling their respective javadocs.

Here are a few links of interest:

1. [*.jar.properties explained](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/35702/)
2. [How to attach sources or docs for external libraries in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793727/how-to-attach-sources-or-docs-for-external-libraries-in-eclipse-adt-android)
3. [How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)
4. [How to import third party libraries in Android Studio](http://www.dfg-team.com/android-tutorial-import-third-party-libraries-android-studio/?lang=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find path-settings in **[project > .idea > libraries]**

if you add 'Parse-1.5.0' library, **[project > .idea > libraries]** directory have **Parse_1_5_0.xml** file.

insert java-doc and source file to **app > libs** then
edit **Parse_1_5_0.xml** file.

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Parse-1.5.0">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/Parse-1.5.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/Parse-1.5.0-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/Parse-1.5.0-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Comment: Up to 0.8.+ now...and just got it working using the proscribed technique. TYVM.

Answer (score 3):

That is working

Problem is that this xml file is generated by gradle. So if you sync your project with gradle files you will lose your changes. So don't forget to add it again.

Is there any way to avoid that ?