# Adding source to a jar library in Android Studio project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, libraries

I have an app which uses a 3rd party library - [Simple Facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) - to access the Facebook Graph APIs. This **3rd party library itself internally uses** the Facebook SDK as a library.

---

#### I have few questions regarding this -

- Since the library is 3rd party, should it also be included in the APK? 
  [image: Scope] 
  If so, then it gives an error.
  [image: Scope Exception]
  **NOTE:** Could someone also explain the meaning of `Compile, Provided, APK, Test compile, Debug compile and Release compile`.

---

- My Project structure is like this - 
  [image: Part 1] 
  [image: Part 2] 
  [image: Part 3] 
  Is the project structure right or should the Facebook SDK be not included at all.

---

#### How do we add source/docs to a library?

We can attach source files/jars to a library jar in eclipse (as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579339/2863440)). This makes it very easy to read the documentation of the `imports` used. Is there any thing similar to this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in your `app's build.gradle`.

[image]

It will compile `jar` file in the `libs folder` under the `app folder`.

[image]

So, you need to add `simple-facebook-2.2.jar` or `simple-facebook-1.2.jar` in that `libs folder`.

At this point I think you good to go.

Comment: After the setup in 'Project Settings' the build.gradle has following entry -
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    apk project(':Simple Facebook')
}`
However, my doubt is about the 'apk' or 'Compile' or other things that we put in Scope in 'Project Settings'. Also, will this generated jar file be available in the APK?

Comment: If you `compile the jar`, it will `available in the apk`

Comment: To test it again, I deleted the previously generated jar - `simple-facebook-2.2.jar` - in the `libs` folder, changed the scope to 'Compile', now when I build the project, it doesn't show the jar file anymore but it also doesn't give any errors. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 6):

**Add source code / docs**

There doesn't seem to be a central place in the Project config. What I usually do is that I Ctrl + click on an imported class in the code editor. In case there are no source attached just yet, it displays the *Attach Sources..* button on top.